# How to return the data from django signal?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-signals

I am using Django-rest for developing the API. In my case, when the user posts the data, I have to process the posted data (It will take 2-3 min). I wrote the Django signal for preprocessing data. My signal.py file looks like this,

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=ExposureIndex)
def calculate_exposure(instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    ear_table = instance.ear_index.name
    haz_dir = instance.hazard_index.file.path

    # calling celery task
    task = exposure_calculation.delay(ear_table,haz_dir)

    return task.id
```

And my celery calculation function is here,

```py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def exposure_calculation(self, ear_table, haz_dir):
    progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)

    CalculateExposure(ear_table, haz_dir)

    return 'Done'
```

My django-rest view function is looks like this,

```py
class ExposureIndexViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ExposureIndex.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExposureIndexSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

My question is when the user posts the data, I want to return the task.id instead of returning the actual response (I tried to return it from the Django signal but it is not returning in the actual API). Can anyone suggest to me how to return `task.id` instantly when the user posts the `exposureIndexData`?

Comment: You won't be able to return anything from signal. Instead you probably need to implement a loader on JS making requests to backend/waiting for response to fetch task ID when it's ready (created, stored in DB, or whatever else option you can use in your case)

Comment: the process is so heavy that is why you are putting it in a celery task. http request and response is synchronous and the task on the other hand is asynchronous. So you can't return the id anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should override the `create` method in `views.py` rather than creating the signal instance. Do something like this in views.py file

```py
class ExposureIndexViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ExposureIndex.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExposureIndexSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        instance = response.data
        ear_table = instance['ear_table']
        haz_dir = instance['haz_dir']

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)

        task = exposure_calculation.delay(ear_table,haz_dir)

        return Response({'task_id': task.id})
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using signals u can simply send response through your view

```
def post(self,request):
  #create database manaully
  task=exposure_calculation.delay(ear_table,haz_dir)
  return Response({"message",task.id})
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Actually, I have to send the response through my `views.py`